# React, ho to redirect to error pag when id is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-navigation, custom-error-pages

I would like to redirect to the error page when the id is not correct. here it is the code of my component :

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import card from "./card.scss";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Card({ id, title, cover }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if(/*some condition*/) {
    navigate("/*");
}
 
  return (
    <div style={card} className="logements">
      <p>{title}</p>
      <img
        src={cover}
        alt=""
        onClick={(e) => {
          navigate(`/Logement/${id}`);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Card.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  cover: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Card;type here
```

Thank you in advance for your help

I would like to redirect to the error page when the id is not correct.

Comment: Does your code not work?

Answer (score 0):

On the page where you define your routes, you should add a Route pointing PageNotFound.

```
import {Route, Routes, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';

<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
    {/* Your routes */}
    <Route path="*" element={<CodeNotFound/>} />
    </Routes>
```

PageNotFound element should look like this:

```
function CodeNotFound() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Code not found</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As your condition already navigates to "/*", you do not need to do any changes there.

Comment: In fact, I found the solution. I had to write the condition into another page ("accomodation"). Thank you for your help !